# how to install a webmin module by command line (bash)?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, webmin

I want to install a module in webmin by command line (bash). How do you do this?

Example:

```
wget https://download.webmin.com/download/modules/text-editor.wbm.gz
```

inside this .gz: text-editor.wbm

```
sudo tar -xf text-editor.wbm.gz
```

[image]

The module (in this case text-editor) when installed via GUI:

[image]

It sends the files to several places. Example:

To **/usr/share/webmin/text-editor**

[image]

To : **/etc/webmin/text-editor**

[image]

To: **/var/webmin/modules/text-editor** (empty):

[image]

**Important:**

Webmin installation methods used in my test:

Method 1:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
wget -q http://www.webmin.com/jcameron-key.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt -y install webmin
```

[Method 2](http://www.webmin.com/deb.html):

```
wget https://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/webadmin/webmin_1.910_all.deb
sudo dpkg --install webmin_1.910_all.deb
```

I asked the author ([Jamie Cameron](http://www.webmin.com/about.html)) no response to the date, because he is the author of webmin and [the author of the module](http://www.webmin.com/cgi-bin/search_third.cgi?search=editor) that I try to install

```
Text Editor 1.4
Description Provides a simple interface for editing text files, with a history of recently-edited files.
Download    text-editor.wbm.gz
Author  Jamie Cameron
Last updated    2007-04-18 11:27:19
```

**Update:**

I have managed to make a script that installs the text-editor module. It is not very "elegant", but it works:

`sudo chmod +x text-editor.sh && sudo ./text-editor.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

fshare=/usr/share/webmin/text-editor
fetc=/etc/webmin/text-editor
fvar=/var/webmin/modules/text-editor

if [ ! -d $fshare ]; then mkdir -p $fshare; fi
if [ ! -d $fetc ]; then mkdir -p $fetc; fi
if [ ! -d $fvar ]; then mkdir -p $fvar; fi
touch $fetc/files
wget -c https://download.webmin.com/download/modules/text-editor.wbm.gz
tar -xf text-editor.wbm.gz
cp -f -R text-editor/* $fshare
cp text-editor/config $fetc
sed -i '$ s/$/ text-editor/' /etc/webmin/webmin.acl
sh -c 'echo "text-editor=1" >> /etc/webmin/installed.cache'
/etc/init.d/webmin restart
```

However, there should be a better method to install any webmin module by command line

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to creator Jamie Cameron it runs like this:

[image]

So, In my case it would be:

```
sudo /usr/share/webmin/install-module.pl text-editor.wbm
```

Answer (score 1):

> Introduction
>   --------- Webmin is designed to allow the easy addition of new modules without changing any of the existing code. A module can be thought of
>   as something like a Photoshop plugin or iPhone application - it can be
>   written by someone other than the developers of Webmin and distributed
>   under a license the developer chooses.
>
> A module should be written to administer one service or server, such
>   as the Unix password file or the Apache web server. Some complex
>   system functions may even be split over several modules - for example,
>   disk partitioning, mounting disks, and disk quota management are 3
>   separate modules in the standard Webmin distribution.
>
> Modules can theoretically be written in any language. However, to make
>   use of the Webmin API Perl version 5.8 or above should be used. A
>   module should be written entirely in Perl, with no C functions or
>   external binary programs. The aim is for modules to be as portable as
>   possible across different Unix systems and CPU types.
>
> Modules written in other languages will not be displayed using the
>   standard Webmin UI and will not be able to call its API. For these
>   reasons, using Perl is strongly recommended.
>
> At their simplest, modules are really just directories of CGI programs
>   that Webmin's web server runs. However, there are certain rules that
>   should be followed to make sure that they work with the Webmin API,
>   main menu, and access control system. Even though you can just stick
>   any existing CGI script into a module directory, this is not a good
>   idea.
>
> ### Required Files
>
> Every module has its own directory under the Webmin base directory, in
>   which all the module's `CGI` programs and configuration files must be
>   stored. For example, if the `Webmin` base was `/usr/libexec/webmin`, a
>   module called foobar would be created or installed in
>   `/usr/libexec/webmin/foobar`.
>
> You can find this base directory by looking at the root line in your
>   `/etc/webmin/miniserv.conf` file. It will differ depending on which
>   operating system `Webmin` is installed.
>
> For a module to be displayed on the main `Webmin` menu, it should
>   contain at least the following files. Only `module.info` is mandatory
>   though.
>
> `module.info`
>       This file contains information about the module and the operating systems it runs under. See below for details on its format.
>   images/icon.gif
>       The icon displayed on the main menu for this module. The icon should be 48x48 pixels and should use the same colour scheme as the
>   other icons on the main menu.  lang/en
>       The text strings used by this module, as explained in the Internationalization section of this documentation. `install_check.pl`
>       Program that checks to see if the service or program is installed and usable, returning a non-zero value if so.
>
> Each module name on `Webmin's` left menu is a link to the module
>   directory. Thus you must have an index.cgi file to be displayed when
>   the user clicks on the link. A typical module contains many `.cgi`
>   programs that are linked to from index.cgi, each of which performs
>   some function such as displaying a form or saving inputs from a form.
>
> When you first create a new module, it will not be in the allowed list
>   of any Webmin user and so you will not be able to see it in the main
>   menu. To fix this, you must first delete the file
>   `/etc/webmin/module.infos.cache` to clear the cache of known modules.
>   Then to make your module visible, either edit the file
>   `/etc/webmin/webmin.acl` or use the Webmin Users module to grant
>   yourself access.

https://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Module_Development

---

I found a guide to the `webmin module installation and removal` like you are trying:

https://www.smarthomebeginner.com/install-webmin-modules/

https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/cms/how-to-install-a-webmin-control-panel-and-modules/

and here:

Here is a module download page:

http://www.webmin.com/standard.html

here are all third party modules:

http://www.webmin.com/cgi-bin/search_third.cgi?modules=1

---

Use a prebuilt `rpm` or `deb` package:

The current Webmin distribution is available in various package formats for download from:

[https://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/webadmin/webmin_1.910_all.deb 14.8 MB](https://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/webadmin/webmin_1.910_all.deb)

http://webmin.com/download.html

If you want to use the apt command for deb files, use it like this:

```
sudo apt install path_to_deb_file
```

If you want to use dpkg command for installing deb packages, here’s how to do it:

```
sudo dpkg -i path_to_deb_file
```

In both commands, you should replace the path_to_deb_file with the path and name of the deb file you have downloaded.

### From the github page:

> Requirements
>
> Perl 5.10 or higher. Installation
>
> Webmin can be installed in two different ways:
>
> By downloading a pre-built package, available for different distributions 
>    (CentOS, Fedora, SuSE, Mandriva, Debian, Ubuntu, Solaris
>   and other) from our download page;
>
> Note: It is highly recommended to
>   add repository to your system for having automatic updates.
>
> By downloading, extracting source file, and running setup.sh script, with no
>   arguments, which will setup to run it directly from
>   this directory, or with a command-line argument, such as targeted
>   directory.
>
> Note: If you are installing Webmin on Windows system, you
>   must run the command perl setup.pl instead. The Windows version
>   depends on several programs, and modules that may not be part of the
>   standard distribution. You will need process.exe commmand, sc.exe
>   command, and Win32::Daemon Perl module.

Comment: Please read my question carefully. Thank you

Comment: @ajcg Yes I saw this later, sorry, does the first link help??

Comment: Now test your method (.deb) and the same result. I can not install the module via command line (which is what I ask). The "howto" you put in your answer are for GUI. Anyway, I appreciate your explanation

Comment: @ajcg thank you again sorry for rushing into it

Comment: Even though your answer does not answer the question, the explanation is very good and illustrative and complements the question. Thank you for your contribution

Answer (score 0):

The `*.wbm.gz` seems to be a tar ball file of the directory of the webmin module.  So, I believe but have not utterly checked it yet that you can simply extract the archive in the Webmin directory as follows. On RHEL, the Webmin directory is `/usr/libexec/webmin`.    On Ubuntu, the Webmin directory is `/usr/share/webmin`.  please check.

To remove the module, simply

```
 # Be carefull with rm -rf, no *,?,. !
 # RH
 rm -rf /usr/libexec/webmin/text-editor
 # Debian-Ubuntu
 rm -rf /usr/share/webmin/text-editor
```

But someone has already created a installer

```
 #RH
 /usr/libexec/webmin/install-module.pl 
 # Debian-Ubuntu
 /usr/share/webmin/install-module.pl
```